# Creating cyclical GraphQL types in Go

Tags: go, graphql

I am trying to create two GraphQL types, Item and Listing, which contain instances of each other as fields. In GraphQL type language they would be:

```
type Item {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    ...
    listings: [Listing]!
}

type Listing {
    id: ID!
    price: Int!
    ...
    item: Item!
}
```

(... represents irrelevant omitted fields)

I've seen other projects do this so I know it's possible, but I'm having difficulty doing this with [github.com/graphql-go/graphql](https://github.com/graphql-go/graphql). From what I've learned online the way to do this using Go would be:

```
var ItemType graphql.Type = graphql.NewObject(
    graphql.ObjectConfig {
        Name: "Item",
        Fields: graphql.Fields {
            "id": &graphql.Field {
                Type: graphql.ID,
             },
             "name": &graphql.Field {
                Type: graphql.String,
             },
             ...
             "listings": &graphql.Field {
                Type: graphql.NewList(ListingType),
             },
        },
    },
)

var ListingType graphql.Type = graphql.NewObject(
    graphql.ObjectConfig {
        Name: "Listing",
        Fields: graphql.Fields {
            "id": &graphql.Field {
                Type: graphql.ID,
             },
             "price": &graphql.Field {
                Type: graphql.Int,
             },
             ...
             "item": &graphql.Field {
                Type: ItemType,
             },
        },
    },
)
```

but this results in an initialization loop:

```
./test.go:9:5: initialization loop:
        /home/william/Desktop/test.go:9:5: ItemType refers to
        /home/william/Desktop/test.go:26:5: ListingType refers to
        /home/william/Desktop/test.go:9:5: ItemType
```

I understand that this happens because the compiler needs to know the size of ItemType in order to determine the size of ListingType in order to determine the size of ItemType (and on and on...) but I'm not sure how to get around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [recommended way](https://github.com/graphql-go/graphql/issues/322) of handling this is using `AddFieldConfig`:

```
houseType := &graphql.Object{...}
residentType := &graphql.Object{...}

houseType.AddFieldConfig("residents", &graphql.Field{Type: graphql.NewList(residentType)})
residentType.AddFieldConfig("houses",  &graphql.Field{Type: graphql.NewList(houseType)})
```